# Is there a way to send the textarea placeholder text behind the cursor caret in Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

Is there a way to send the textarea placeholder text behind the cursor in Safari?

Other browsers show the placeholder behind the cursor caret but safari shows it in front which looks quite odd:

[image]

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/s5zymdch/

```
<textarea rows="1" placeholder="Full Name"></textarea>

textarea{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40pt;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to fix this, it may just be a browser issue. Try changing the background off the textarea and see if that works, or just remove and placeholder and add a span above the textarea with the text. I'm sure it works fine in other browsers.
I tried it out myself and it seems to work fine for me in safari. I'm not able to identify the problem.

Comment: If you are ok with positioning both the placeholder and the textarea you can do https://jsfiddle.net/vL70dsh9/

Comment: @Kaiido interesting. If I remove the `position`, then it doesn't;t work. But if I change it to `absolute` (which I need for my own use case), it continues to work. Not sure why it behaves this way. Anyway, thanks, this solution works for me. If you post as answer, I will accept it. With `absolute`: https://jsfiddle.net/k2qy96bd/

Comment: @Kaiido I just did more testing with that `::placeholder` way and it has a bug where if you apply background color using `::hover` or `::focus` then the placeholder will disappear.